# Assign values to a screen variable from a flow variable

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, customization, screen-flow

I have a flow where it has:

1. Screen flow consisting of some inputs (text, picklist, etc...)
2. Assignment to a new lead record variable (All input values are assigned to the respective fields of the lead)
3. Apex Action to perform some validations and return the valid lead (e.g. validate text fields do not consist of mixed greek and latin characters and also capitalize characters etc)
4. Condition (If apex returns that we have a validation error (mixed characters), i want to navigate to the first screen, and also update the screen elements with the capitalized characters.

My problem is, i cannot find a way to assign the capitalized characters to the screen elements. For example, if the user input on FirstName field is 'Giorgos', apex will return 'GIORGOS'. This will also update my lead record returned, however i want also to update the screen Element from 'Giorgos' to "GIORGOS".

To be more specific, the problem for me is in the following assignment:
[image]

I just want to "reverse" the assignment but i can't. The {!Lead.Status} contains the value Apex has returned to me (it is checked that it does return the value correctly). The Lead_Status_Field is the API Name of the screen element. But i want the screen element to get the value of {!Lead.Status} and not the opposite. However, in the variables selection i cannot select the {!Lead_Status_Field}. How can i solve this?

Comment: Have you looked at the Flow debug and Apex debug to determine when the text is being converted to uppercase?  Please [edit] your post to include the results.

Comment: Hi David, i updated the question.